# Japanese chat romaji based acronym/abbreviation usage and meanings

Tags: abbreviations

I know that ww means laugh/warau. Are there any other romaji-based acronyms used in japanese chats only? Please provide the acronym and meaning if possible. I searched online and found many hiragana and katakana expressions. I am focused on romaji based  acronyms.

Comment: https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [KY語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/KY%E8%AA%9E) in Wikipedia. There is even [a dictionary for this type of words](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4861914094), but this trend is something in the past, and most of them are completely forgotten.

As of 2019, ones that are still sometimes used include:

- **mjd?**: マジで?  "Really?", "Are you sure?"
- **ktkr**: キタコレ "Yay!", "Here it comes!"
- **kwsk**: 詳しく "Tell me more about that."
- **gkbr**: [ガクブル](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB)
- **ggrks**: ググレカス "Google it yourself", "[giyf](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=giyf)"
- **ks**: カス/クソ "shit / crap"
- **BBA**: ババア "old woman"
- **KY**: 空気読めない "cannot read between the lines", "insensitive"
- **JK**: 常識的に考えて "based on common sense", "if you think logically"
- **G**: ゴキブリ "cockroach"
- **TKG**: 卵かけご飯 "[egg on rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamago_kake_gohan)"
- **JD**: 女子大生 "female university student"
- **JK**: 女子高生 "high school girl"
- **JC**: 女子中学生 "middle school girl"
- **JS**: 女子小学生 "elementary school girl"
- **DT**: 童貞 "(male) virgin"
- **NTR**: [寝取られ "cuckold"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52069/5010)