# Do any other widely used romaji based acronyms besides KK and NHK translate directly into Japanese words?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

Do any other widely used acronyms besides KK (Kabushiki Kaisha) and NHK (Nihon Housou Kyoukai) translate directly into Japanese? I have seen DIY, SS, NTT, JR, and LDK to name a few, but the terms would have English word meanings. Thank You!

Comment: Do you remember you recently [asked a very similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69903/5010)? What makes this question different from the previous one?

Comment: What answer do you expect to this question? A simple 'yes'? An exhaustive list of all acronyms? What will you do with the information?

Comment: I will reword the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you ask "why". There is no such a rule that Latin acronyms must be made only from pure English words. Here are some nationally- or globally-known organizations based on romanized Japanese:

- [**YKK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YKK) = **吉**田**工**業**株**式会社, world's largest zipper manufacturer
- [**SNK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNK) = **新日**本**企**画, game software company best known for *King of Fighters* franchise
- [**TDK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDK) = **東**京**電**気**化**学工業, best known as a compact cassette manufacturer
- [**DNP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dai_Nippon_Printing) = **大日**本印刷 (P = printing), Japan's one of the largest printing companies
- **KNT** = **近**畿**日**本**ツ**ーリスト, travel agency
- [**DHC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHC_Corporation) = **大**学**翻**訳**セ**ンター, now known for cosmetics and supplement

And there are also many [slangy romaji abbreviations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69906/5010) like KY (空気読めない) and JK (女子高生).

Comment: Latin letters can only be used because acronyms can not be written using Kanji characters. The term must be written out entirely if using Kanji.

Comment: 細かいですがTDKは、「東京電気化学工業」ですね。

Comment: @kimiTanaka 写し間違えました…ありがとうございます